# Call a function defined in one JSP file in another JSP file

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have two jsp files.
In one of them i have a function which has a variable, say x, that I need to use in another jsp file. So I made a variable , say y, outside the function and in that function, I called a serVar() function which sets y to x. Something like ...

```
<script>
.
.
.
var y;
function someFunction()
{
var x;
.
.
setVar(x);
}

function setVar(x)
{
y=x;
}

function getVar()
{
return y;
}
.
.
</script>
```

To use it in another jsp file, I also made a function like getVar() in the same file as shown above. How can I call this function getVar() in another jsp file?

Comment: Including jsp into another jsp will result in execution jsp scriplets and/or other java codes of the included jsp. Ideally you should have your java script into external js and import js files using script tag in the jsp/html page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Including jsp into another jsp will result in execution jsp scriplets and/or other java codes of the included jsp. Ideally you should have your java script into external js and import js files using `script` tag in the jsp/html page.

However, if you still want to go for it, try using `jsp:include`.

```
<jsp:include page="your.jsp"/>  <!-- jsp with getVar() defined -->
<script>
  alert(getVar());
</script>
```

Or you can also use `include` directive:

```
<%@include file="your.jsp" %>  <!-- jsp with getVar() defined -->
<script>
    alert(getVar());
</script>
```

Comment: I think I cannot have the function in another file. I'll reframe my question.

Answer (score 0):

Move the function from the inline script block to a seperate file and the include the file in both of your jsp files, where you want use the like this:

```
<script src='<pathToFile>'></script>
```

The script must be included/run before you can use the function, so put it above the code, where you need the function